# Why is urllib not working with my python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to get my program to read a website inserted by a user. My mistake is probably really silly, because I'm a bit of a newbie, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

This is what I wrote:

```
def open_website():
 website = input("Hello, enter website")
 import webbrowser
 webbrowser.open(website)
 find_words()

def find_words():
 import urllib
 web_read = urllib.urlopen(website)
 text = web_read.read()
 print (text)




open_website()
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what error you're getting, including the full traceback.

Comment: What is the output of the program? What happens? What input are you putting in?

Answer (score 1):

You used `Python 3.x` and you must use `urllib.request` not `urllib.urlopen`

Also, you must pass the `website` to `find_words`, change your code to this:

```
def open_website():
    website = input("Hello, enter website")
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open(website)
    find_words(website)

def find_words(website):
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    web_read = urlopen(website)
    text = web_read.read()
    print (text)

open_website()
```